# css список ul выстроить в столбцы

Tags: css, ul

нужно построить li в 2 столбца. пробовал свойство
`ul{columns:2}`
но получаются столбцы
1 6
2 7
3 8
4 9
5 10

а мне нужно
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10

если добавить

```
li{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 500px;
}
```

то они выстраиваются но при уменьшении масштаба количество столбцов увеличивается
попробовал так:

```
li:nth-child(even):after{
    content:"\A"; 
    white-space:normal; 
}
```

получаю то же самое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ol {
  counter-reset: count;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ol>li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ol>li:before {
  counter-increment: count;
  content: counter(count) " ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

Вариант 2

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ol {
  counter-reset: count;
  padding: 0;
}

ol:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  line-height: 0;
}

ol>li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

ol>li:before {
  counter-increment: count;
  content: counter(count) " ";
}

ol>li:nth-of-type(2n + 3) {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: вроде работает, но нужно чтобы при уменьшении масштаба элементы не растягивались

Comment: сделал ul { width: 1000 px;} так пойдет

Answer (score 1):

flex:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  
}

li {
  width: 50%;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item-1</li>
  <li>item-2</li>
  <li>item-3</li>
  <li>item-4</li>
  <li>item-5</li>
  <li>item-6</li>
  <li>item-7</li>
  <li>item-8</li>
  <li>item-9</li>
  <li>item-10</li>
</ul>
```